# How to disable integrated vs studio 2019 terminal on mac

Tags: macos, terminal, visual-studio-2019

I have been using the terminal that is not built-in vs studio for some time, but for some reason, the built-in terminal keeps popping up when I run my code recently.

How can I fix this on a mac?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

For anyone who wants to know:

Step 1: Go to vsstudio and go to preferences

[image]

Step 2: Scroll down until you find the word terminal

[image]

Step 3: Finally untick the integrated terminal box!

[image]